# Syslog connection to Logstash not resetting

Tags: linux, logstash, rsyslog

We have a setup with one Logstash server (1.4.2, using embedded Elasticsearch) to receive logs from a number of other clients (via TCP and from their `rsyslogd` instances).  One issue that now happens repeatedly is that one by one messages from hosts aren't received anymore, however there are no error messages anywhere to be seen.

It basically looks like the Logstash host can't process the amount of incoming messages and the connections are left in a weird state; I did `lsof`/`strace` on the client `rsyslogd` instances and also captured some traffic on both clients and server and it seems that while the clients still have a connection open:

```
rsyslogd 30088 syslog    1u  IPv4           14878202       0t0        TCP 10.129.X.X:47492->10.129.X.X:5544 (ESTABLISHED)
```

, that connection is basically broken as the server (port `5544`) sends TCP Zero Window messages, which, as [Wireshark tells me](http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP%20ZeroWindow), is basically Logstash not keeping up (CPU usage on the host isn't always at max, but regularly at about 75% on all four cores).

My question is thus:  Is there are flag / setting / ... to either get the `rsyslogd` daemons to back off / reconnect in such a situation, or for Logstash to properly close connections if it can't keep up?  (Is this a known problem?, because I wasn't able to find any relevant links.)

Edit:  In the meantime we've changed the input plugin to `tcp` instead of `syslog`, which, together with manual `grok` parsing, seems to handle the load better.  I'd still like to understand the original problem though.

Answer (score 0):

These are the params you're looking for:

```
Action.ResumeInterval="30"
Action.ResumeRetryCount="-1"
```

[Here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/actions.html) you can find all the params available

This is the example of a generic rs:

```
ruleset(name="myruleset_name"){
    action(
    type="omfwd"
    Target="destination_fqdn_ip"
    Port="destination_port"
    Protocol="tcp"
    Action.ResumeInterval="30"
    Action.ResumeRetryCount="-1"
    )
    stop
}
```

Note that actually the problem relies on the dst: the logstash server is not able to cope with the incoming load (rsyslog output), so you should take a look carefully the dst server.
A recurrent TCP Zero Window is huge problem as it potentially translates into data loss (buffer overhead), data peaks and valleys, data not in real time, etc ..

Hope that helps.